# error C2512 no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++

ok so im having this issue involving two classes.

Dice.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <random>

using std::random_device;
using std::uniform_int_distribution;

class Dice
{
public:
    Dice(int Sides);
    int roll(void);

protected:
    int nSides;
    random_device generator;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution;
};
```

Dice.cpp:

```
#include "Dice.h"



Dice::Dice(int Sides)
{
    nSides=Sides;
}



int Dice::roll(void)
{
    random_device generator;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,nSides);

    return distribution(generator);
}

DmgCalc.h:

#pragma once

#include "CharSheet.h"
#include "Dice.h"
class DmgCalc
{
public:
    DmgCalc(CharSheet P1, CharSheet P2);

    bool Dodge();

    int Attack();

    int Roll();
protected:

    int nP1Con, nP1Str, nP1Dex;
    int nP2Con, nP2Dex, nP2Hlth;

    Dice d6;
};
```

DmgCalc.cpp:

```
#include "DmgCalc.h"


DmgCalc::DmgCalc(CharSheet P1, CharSheet P2)
{
    nP1Str=P1.getStr();
    nP1Dex=P1.getDex();

    nP2Con=P2.getCon();
    nP2Dex=P2.getDex();
    nP2Hlth=P2.getHlth();

    Dice d6(6);
}


bool DmgCalc::Dodge()
{
    return ((nP1Dex + d6.roll())-(nP2Dex + d6.roll()) > 0);
}

int DmgCalc::Attack()
{
    nP2Hlth-=((nP1Str + d6.roll())-(nP2Con));

    return nP2Hlth;
}

int DmgCalc::Roll()
{
    return d6.roll();
}
```

Whenever I try and compile I get this error:

```
Error   2   error C2512: 'Dice' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

If I create another constructor for Dice with the format `void Dice(void);` it works just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't see anything here trying to use it, but I do see a local variable in the constructor that should be a data member.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but data members are usually `private`, not `protected`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialise the `Dice` member in the initialiser list of your constructor

```
DmgCalc::DmgCalc(CharSheet P1, CharSheet P2)
    : d6(20)
{
```

Anything not initialised here will have its default constructor called.  `Dice` does not have a default constructor, hence the compiler error.